# 8051 External /WR signal not generated when UART bootloader is used after reset

Tags: external, microcontroller, lcd, 8051, memory-mapping

Goal of the project: To connect an LCD with 8051 as an external memory-mapped I/O device

Problem: Given the following details, my 8051 controller just does not generate an external RD/WR command as required for the rest of the code to work.

Previous work: I used 8051 port 3 pins to generate EN, R/W and RS signals and got it to work. Therefore, I know that my command sequence is working fine. However, this was a really inefficient way of using the LCD because the enable pulse was generated by setting and resetting a port pin. I wish to connect the LCD using the external WR/RD signals and mapping it as a memory-mapped IO device. I have worked through the timing diagrams and the overall block diagram is attached here. As you can see (in the block diagram), the R/W line of LCD is activated using the most significant 6 pins of port 2 so that the LCD gets activated only at the right memory addresses. This operation (implemented in an SPLD) also serves to ensure the delay required at the LCD to ensure the minimum setup time after Port 2 pins 0,1 are used to set inputs at R/W and RS signals of LCD.

Additional hardware info: I have attached a spice diagram to show how the rest of my 8051 is connected. The one thing that is not included there is this: "I use a momentary pushbutton and pull-down resistor for /PSEN, and hold that button when coming out of reset in order to force bootloader operation; then, after the bootloader has started, I release that button to eliminate drive fight issues on the /PSEN line. I use a header/jumper for the /EA input to ensure it is high. Note that if you use these hardware conditions to enter the bootloader when you come out of reset, then the Atmel bootloader is entered regardless of the values of BLJB, BSB, and SBV."

Software used: I am using the paulmon2 to test my code. Programming is done using Flip utility: Flip 3.4.7 through the serial port. A serial emulator program (TeraTerm) is used to communicate with the microcontroller. The microcontroller first executes the paulmon code as well as its extra commands that have been programmed into it before the current user code at 0x2000 location. An extra command allows the user to jump to this code using 'J' command and then giving the address for memory: 0x2000. This calls the current
program and executes it. This is where my code resides and executes from.

The addresses used to map LCD are the following:

```
LCD_INSTR_WR: 0xA8FF  ---> Used to write commands to LCD controller.
This includes all initialization and setup and management commands.
LCD_INSTR_RD: 0xA9FF ---> Used to read command. Done only to read the busy 
flag or the current address counter. This is valid only for a single
instruction on the LCD.
LCD_DATA_WR: 0xAAFF ---> Used to write Data to the current address which has 
been set either in DDRAM or CGRAM given the LCD_INSTR_WR above.
LCD_DATA_RD: 0xABFF ----> Used to read Data from the current address which 
has been set either in DDRAM or CGRAM given the LCD_INSTR_WR above.
```

The code snippet I write in C to write the external memory:

```
//Global variables
volatile unsigned char xdata *LCD_INSTR_WR = (char xdata *) 0xA8FF;
volatile unsigned char xdata *LCD_INSTR_RD = (char xdata *) 0xA9FF;
volatile unsigned char xdata *LCD_DATA_WR = (char xdata *) 0xAAFF;
volatile unsigned char xdata *LCD_DATA_RD = (char xdata *) 0xABFF;
/// More code
//Write command example
lcdbusywait();
* LCD_DATA_WR = cc;
```

Earlier tests one to figure out the problem:

1. I have tried writing to the memory locations above 2000 using the paulmon memory edit instructions and they write the memory locations alright. Even /WR command is generated in this case as observed (but I have not properly measured/counted the accesses and /WR edge changes.
2. I have used the logic analyser to confirm that the address (and consequently RS and RW) and data (0x30H command in the beginning) are coming to the ports as expected. ALE is being generated.
3. I have verified that AUXR register bit EXTRAM is set (AUXR = 0x0E). Also, since EXTRAM is set by default, I tried to remove my initialization code for AUXR completely and that didn’t work either.
4. I was not sure that the C code that I have written for the XRAM address accesses is correct. However, I went on to check the .asm file and (unless I am neglecting something very minute), the assembly code generated does assign a 0x30h value as immediate data to a register A and uses a “MOVX @dptr,A” instruction to write this value to external memory.

Finally, this is my first post at Stack overflow so the formatting may be off and I do realize this is an extremely long post. Apologies for that. Let me know if you need to see the code files or the compiled hex file or other details. All your help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: There are many Atmel 8051 variants available, which one do you actually use? Some of those ship with *internal* XRAM.

Comment: @TurboJ I am using the AT89C51. Apologies for late response. I was able to get the /WR, /RD signals working. I believe the problem earlier was related to how I initialized the AUXR register. My initial value was off by a bit and I didnt realize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
volatile unsigned char xdata *LCD_INSTR_WR = (char xdata *) 0xA8FF;
```

I guess `LCD_INSTR_WR` should have address`0xA8FF` value.

You can try by using

```
#define LCD_INSTR_WR  XBYTE[0xA8FF]
```

and then

```
LCD_INSTR_WR  = cc;
```

or

```
char xdata LCD_INSTR_WR  _at_ 0xA8FF;  //This will declare the LCD_INSTR_WR at location 0xA8FF-
```

You may need to look into the data sheet of the micro controller how to configure extrnal memory

```
LCD_INSTR_WR = cc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sudhee. As I commented earlier, I had to redo the whole code adding one by one the functions to debug. Eventually, it turned out to be a problem of how I was initializing my AUXR register. The problem was made hard to track because I was nearly at the end of my internal RAM usage and a pointer was accessing wrongly. In short, it was not related to the pointers that you refer to in your comment. Thanks again for your time and help.